# Handling large source code file for form in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, tabs, partial-classes, regions

I have a form which has three tabs. Now each of the tab has some 15 - 20 functions. So when combined, I have around 50 methods and it becomes quite cumbersome to handle such a big class. Are there any better ways of handling such a large file. Do these methods help:
1) three partial classes
2) seperate classes(non partial) for each tab
3) regions

Please share your experiences.
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 4):

You could separate each of the tabs into separate user controls. Or even go for a more granular level than that.

Comment: Not much knowledge about user controls. Are there any links for tutorials and understanding?

Comment: @tarun_tenniso http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302342.aspx although a quick google for Winforms user controls will come up with lots of examples.

Answer (score 4):

For each `TabPage`of your `TabControl` do the following:

Drag a `Panel` from the toolbar into the `TabPage`. Set the `Dock` property of the panel to `Fill`.

In the Solution Explorer, create a new element of type Windows Forms.

Set `FormBorderStyle` in your new form to `None`

Use the following code in the form containing the TabControl

```
public MainFrm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var subFrm = new SubFrm();
    subFrm.TopLevel = false;
    subFrm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    panelInTabPage.Controls.Add(subFrm);
    subFrm.Show();
}
```

Now you can store the logic of each subform in its own source file.

Answer (score 2):

For static tabs I usually segregate into their own partial class. Any functions which are shared between I try to put in a single separate class and call when needed.

Comment: This is a lot cleaner than user controls. Simply move your code (most likely in regions) from the main form into several partial class files in the same namespace, derived from Form. Don't make the sibling files as dependent on the main form for maintenance reasons. Done in 2 minutes...

Answer (score 1):

I have come across this problem before and had the requirement that we use no third party controls so that the application could be easily handed over to a third party. To get around this we had a main form which we set `IsMdiContainer = true` and dock a `TabControl` to the to of the main form so that only the `TabItem`s are visible and the contents is not.

Now, this is not the nicest, but it solves the problem and allows you to write the contents of each tab as a seperate form having its own class etc. On the main form set the load event to load the relevant forms into you `TabControl`.

*Note, you can replace the use of `Form`s in what follows with `UserControl`s but you will use the ability to have the main form as an MdiContainer and will have to use a `Panel` to dock controls and add some code to bring each user control to front.*

```
private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try {
        LoadMdiForms();
    }
    finally {   
        mdiTabControl.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }       
}
```

Then set up a `List<Form> MdiChildForms { get; set; }` and add you forms

```
private void LoadMdiForms()
{
    createDbForm = new CreateDbForm();
    MdiChildForms.Add(createDbForm);
    valForm = new ValidationForm();
    MdiChildForms.Add(valForm);
    // et al.

    foreach (Form mdiChild in MdiChildForms)
    {
        mdiChild.MdiParent = this;
        mdiChild.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        mdiChild.Show();
    }
}
```

Now set up an `MainForm_MdiChildActivate` event handler

```
private void MainForm_MdiChildActivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.ActiveMdiChild == null)
        mdiTabControl.Visible = false; // If no child forms, hide tabControl
    else
    {
        // Child form always maximized.
        this.ActiveMdiChild.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized; 

        // If child form is new and has no tabPage, create new tabPage.
        if (this.ActiveMdiChild.Tag == null)
        {
            // Add a tabPage to tabControl with child form caption
            TabPage tp = new TabPage(this.ActiveMdiChild.Text);
            tp.Tag = this.ActiveMdiChild;
            tp.Parent = mdiTabControl;
            mdiTabControl.SelectedTab = tp;
            this.ActiveMdiChild.Tag = tp;
            this.ActiveMdiChild.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(ActiveMdiChild_FormClosed);
        }

        // Make visible if required.
        if (!mdiTabControl.Visible) 
            mdiTabControl.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Now add the event handler on the `TabControl` `SelectedIndexChanged` event

```
// If child form closed, remove tabPage.
private void ActiveMdiChild_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    ((sender as Form).Tag as TabPage).Dispose();
}

private void mdiTabControl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((mdiTabControl.SelectedTab != null) && 
         (mdiTabControl.SelectedTab.Tag != null))
    {
        this.BeginUpdate();
        (mdiTabControl.SelectedTab.Tag as Form).Select();
        this.EndUpdate();
    }
}
```

That's it. You should have a working `TabControl` with atomic `TabItem`s.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Why the down-vote, this is a decent compromise that works!

Answer (score 0):

A few approaches handling GUI components:

- When starting up a new project, we always have some base user control (or at least interface)
- whenever we feel a particular control (other than standard user control) could be used somewhere else, we separate it out as a custom user control.
- We normally segregate all custom user controls to a standalone project.

for your particular issue, you could separate each tab as a standalone custom user control.

some work-through: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302342.aspx